# Find an appropriate function phi, so that if U is uniform on the interval (0,1), then phi(U) is exponential with rate 1

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, self-learning

[image]

I'm not sure what the question is asking for. The cdf?
Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: you should mark this as homework.

Comment: It couldn't be the CDF, because the CDF is bounded, while $\phi$ clearly is not. But it is closely related to the CDF...

Comment: hmm is phi=-log(1-u)

Comment: ding-ding!! (now simulate it to see that its histogram matches an exponential and has mean 1)

Comment: also, by symmetry, you could also use $\phi = -log(u)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: This is a conceptual question. If you've taken a simulation class the answer will be apparent if you recall how to generate random variables.

If you have a continuous, real-valued random variable, $X$ with density function $f(x)$, then $F(x):=\int_0^x f(x) dx$ gives us a function that maps values from the domain of $X$ to the interval $[0,1]$.

Now, the question wants you to find a function that when fed values from a standard uniform random variable generates values from and exponential distribution with rate 1.